# Building PostgreSQL 13.1 relocatable package for all Linux systems

Tags: linux, postgresql

The PostgreSQL used to provide EDB package for Linux x86_64 till version 10.15 like [postgresql-10.15-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz](https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1257417&_ga=2.7456306.1007711620.1607523325-386158011.1603281609).

Now we want to upgrade PostgreSQL to version 13.1 and EDB package for it is not available.

Hence we want to create the package our own using documentation [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-procedure.html). But we are able to compile package but it is not including all required files such and header and libs for SSL, tar.

How to generate a complete relocatable package like postgresql-10.15-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar to run PostgreSQL  as standalone software on RHEL6/7/8 SUSE, SLES12/15 Linux versions.

or

Are there any special instructions to generate PostgreSQL 13.1 package like postgresql-10.15-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar?

Comment: Can't you just "repack" the RPMs?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [the PGDG packages](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/).

Building from source is of course also an option, but I recommend that you do not try to create standalone binary packages. The proper way for that would be linking the software statically, which is not supported by the build process and would require you to have static libraries for all referenced software.

You could attempt to add all linked shared libraries to the software distribution, but you would have to make sure that these libraries are used instead of the ones on the default shared library path, which is difficult.

It seems to me that you are trying to re-invent the wheel here, and the wheel in this case is a docker container. Use that and stop worrying.